# Add values stored in an array

Tags: dimension-expressions

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\begin{document}
\newarray\cws
\cws(0)=3pt
\cws(1)=4pt
\let\a\dimexpr\cws(0)+\cws(1)\relax
\a
\end{document}
```

Error: ! You can't use `\dimexpr' in horizontal mode.

This doesn't work either:

```
\let\a\z@
\advance\a\cws(0)
\advance\a\cws(1)
\a
```

How can I create a sum of elements in an array (arrayjob)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array notation isn't really helping, especially as implemented in your question where it is not expandable so can not be used in lots of places, such as `\dimexpr`.

here is an expandable version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\def\set#1#2#3{\expandafter\def\csname#1#2\endcsname{#3}}
\def\use#1#2{\csname#1#2\endcsname}
\begin{document}

\set{cws}{0}{3pt}
\set{cws}{1}{4pt}


\the\dimexpr\use{cws}{0}+\use{cws}{1}\relax


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the only one I could understand so far without reading some hundred pages of documentation of experimental packages. :-)

Answer (score 6):

That's a job for `expl3`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_nagylzs_cws_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \ArraySet { m }
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_nagylzs_cws_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \ArraySum { m }
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l_tmpa_dim
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_nagylzs_cws_seq
  {
   \dim_add:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { ##1 }
  }
  #1 = \l_tmpa_dim
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ArraySet{3pt,4pt,4ex,1in}
\ArraySum{\dimen0}
\the\dimen0
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

Here is a completely unreadable version of the above code violating all `expl3` standards but sort of fulfilling the least-lines-criterium.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\ArraySet#1{\seq_set_from_clist:Nn\cws{#1}}
\def\ArraySum#1{\dim_zero:N\l_tmpa_dim
  \seq_map_inline:Nn\cws{\dim_add:Nn\l_tmpa_dim{##1}}
  #1=\l_tmpa_dim}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ArraySet{3pt,4pt,4ex,1in}
\ArraySum{\dimen0}
\the\dimen0
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seriously? 16 lines of code to add two values???

Comment: @nagylzs You can add an arbitrary number of values (of course limited by maxdimen). I'll extend my answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing two unnecessary lines from your “reduced version” :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should use `arrayjobx` and not `arrayjob` (the latter is not really compatible with LaTeX).

Secondly, `\let\a\dimexpr` will make `\a` equivalent to `\dimexpr` and try printing `\cws(0)+\cws(1)\relax`; then `\a` will produce an error just like

```
\dimexpr
\end{document}
```

You should use `\newcommand` and not `\let`, but it won't do anyway, because `\cws(0)` is not good inside `\dimexpr, as it requires assignments that are not performed in that context.

Here's a different implementation using `expl3` and its property lists.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareArray}{m}
 {
  \prop_new:c { l_nagylzs_array_#1_prop }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \prop_item:cn { l_nagylzs_array_#1_prop } { ##1 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setarray}{mmm}
 {
  \prop_put:cnn { l_nagylzs_array_#1_prop } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\DeclareArray{cws}
\setarray{cws}{0}{3pt}
\setarray{cws}{1}{4pt}
\setarray{cws}{2}{1in}

\newcommand\foo{\dimexpr\cws{0}+\cws{1}+\cws{2}\relax}

A\hspace{\foo}B

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws{0}+\cws{1}\relax}B

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws{0}\relax}B

\end{document}
```

[image]

A package free version, that however is less flexible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newarray[1]{%
  \newcommand{#1}[1]{\@nameuse{nagylzs@\string#1@##1}}%
}
\newcommand{\set}[3]{\@namedef{nagylzs@\string#1@#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newarray{\cws}
\set\cws{0}{3pt}
\set\cws{1}{4pt}
\set\cws{2}{1in}

\newcommand\foo{\dimexpr\cws{0}+\cws{1}+\cws{2}\relax}

A\hspace{\foo}B

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws{0}+\cws{1}\relax}B

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws{0}\relax}B

\end{document}
```

Explanation. There is no array data type in TeX, so one has to build it. This implementation uses `\csname` which provides a kind of associative memory.

Defining an array simply defines a command for using the values stored with `\set`. The command `\cws{0}` expands to

```
\@nameuse{nagylzs@\string\cws@0}
```

that's the same as

```
\csname nagylzs@\string\cws@0\endcsname
```

Note that `\cws` is “stringified”, so it can appear in `\csname...\endcsname`. The `\set` command does the association: `\set\cws{0}{3pt}` does

```
\@namedef{nagylzs@\string\cws@0}{4pt}
```

which is the same as

```
\expandafter\def\csname nagylzs@\string\cws@0\endcsname{4pt}
```

The association is thus in the name of a macro. The macro name is complicated in order to avoid collisions with other macros.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: Here's a different approach using the `listofitems` package.  EDITED to demonstrate functionality with different unit sets in the array.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{ }
\begin{document}
\def\data{3pt 4ex 1in}% space separated data
\readlist\cws{\data}% reads \data into list named "cws" 

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws[1]+\cws[2]+\cws[3]}B

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws[1]+\cws[2]}B

A\hspace{\dimexpr\cws[1]}B
\end{document}
```

[image]